# How to solve Mouse over error in Selenium IDE Script Recording

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-ide, action-recording

I'm new to Selenium. Currently, I'm trying to automate the testing process of a React Django-based app using Selenium script recording in Selenium IDE. I'm facing repeated issues with mouse click parts.

After I record the process and run it, it breaks on a mouse click script. My testing software has a create, update and delete function.

Most likely, the error comes in clicking the update and delete buttons. So, right now I'm using the `Tab` button to reach the update and delete buttons which is a little time-consuming in the recording process.

[image]

The above given image is where I get the error.

Below is the log of the error:

[image]

Is there any way to overcome this issue or any way to change the script on the error part to make it right?

Also, it would be kind if you suggest to me any other best way to automate testing of my React application other than this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution :

- The methods Actions class has provided for Mouse Hover action:

```
moveToElement(WebElement target)
moveToElement(WebElement target, int xOffset, int yOffset)
```

- Another alternative is :

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.Id("Target_id"));
actions.moveToElement(target).perform();
```

- Suggestion :

  - When we are trying to perform mouse hover, Try if you could have linkText, partialLinkText or tagName to use